# Access via Anydesk to the PC from the subnetwork

Tags: networking, router, ip, anydesk

I need to use Anydesk via LAN even if there is no internet and I need advice to resolve the following:

I have PC in the main network (192.168.254.x) with the gateway 192.168.254.1
In this network there is a router (ext 192.168.254.240, int 192.168.250.1).
In this subnetwork I have PC 192.168.250.x

Question: What should I do to be able to access through Anydesk the PC 250.x from the PC 254.x?

Comment: What is the model number of your router?

Answer (score 0):

I assume those are different subnets (e.g. 192.168.254.0/24 and 192.168.250.0/24). Then there are options:

- Use a router to route packets between the subnets
- Add a second IP from the other subnet to either PC
- Change the subnet so it spans both IP ranges

There is no general answer, it depends on why you are using two subnets in the first place. And of course, you could put both PCs into the same subnet in the first place.